# download sql backup file in mvc

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, file, c#-4.0

I tried to download .bak file in MVC project. I have put below method in my controller and try to call it from my view by passing the existing backup file name e.g test.bak.

```
 public FileResult Download(string fileName)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/backup/"), fileName);
            var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            return File(fileStream, "application/zip");
        }
```

I am expecting my code zip the test.bak file and let me download and extract it at my end but when I tried to extract it, I have ended up with "No archive found" error.

Comment: Hmmm, the second argument should be the mime type of your file. But it want magically convert a bak file to a zip. Is that what you were attempting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to specify right mimetype and fileName as well to download in .bak format

```
  var fileStreamResult = File(fileStream, "application/octet-stream");
        fileStreamResult.FileDownloadName = fileName;
```